# elementos de footer, defecto visual

Tags: html, css

Estoy trabajando en el footer de mi página web, pero tengo un problema y es que al añadir el display fex en el, se me crea una extraño espacio en blanco al fondo del todo y me ocurre justo al especificar que sea flex-direction:column; y no entiendo porque, ya que al quitarlo, no da problemas, desconozco si crea algun padding innecesario o un margin, ademas de ello, no quiero que el nombre y el subtitulo queden tan separados sino que este uno justo debajo del otro y no lo consigo. Adjunto el codigo a continuación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```css
.seccion {

    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;

    width:100%;
    align-items: center; /* Alinea los elementos del flexbox sobre el eje horizontal */
    background-color: rgb(44, 42, 42);
    height: 90px;
    color: white;


    &__titulo
    {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<footer class="seccion">
  <div class="seccion__titulo">
    <p class="text-secondary text-white texto">Nombre de propietario &#169;</p>
    <p>subtitulo</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Inspecciona el elemento que mencionas desde tu navegador, que estilos tiene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solo tienes agregar lo siguiente para formatear las propiedades del navegar

```css
:root *{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.seccion {

left:0px;
bottom:0px;

width:100%;
align-items: center; /* Alinea los elementos del flexbox sobre el eje horizontal */
background-color:  rgb(44, 42, 42);
height: 90px;
color: white;
display: flex;// agregue estos mas para centrarlo 
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;


&__titulo
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

}
```

```html
        <footer class="seccion">
            <div class="seccion__titulo">
              <p class="text-secondary text-white texto">Nombre de propietario &#169;</p>
              <p>subtitulo</p>
            </div>
          </footer>
```